# Can we detect plagiarism from/in a podcast?

Tags: plagiarism, copyright, audio-video-recording

Is there a way to match content

- of an article from a podcast source,
- of a podcast from an article source or
- of a podcast from another podcast source?

I haven't heard of any tool that can check plagiarism from/in an audio source. If such a tool does exist, how efficient and reliable is it?

EDIT: There is no specific purpose for asking this question. It is just out of curiosity, since I am listening to a lot of podcasts nowadays.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question. You might get a more useful answer if you [edit] the question to tell us why you want an answer.

Comment: A data driven AI might be able to do some things. Otherwise it seems like a pretty hard problem.

Comment: Are you asking about plagiarism as a concept about scientific integrity, or just about students breaking the rules about copying stuff? I think the answers being given here are about things from different domains. Student dishonesty is a bit easier since their transgressions are usually less sophisticated.

Comment: Is this a "please help me cheat" question?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that anything currently exists. I don't, however, think the problem is infeasible. But it is very hard.

First, plagiarism is about ideas, not words. One can plagiarize without using any of the original words. Second, plagiarism is about the creation of the ideas and claiming them as your own. Both of these are difficult problems.

First, one would probably need both things to be in a common format, probably written language. This part currently has solutions that mostly work, but it is the easiest part. Second, the actual meaning of the words would need to be extracted and probably also structured in some way.

Finally, the system would need to watch out that the ideas weren't just being *expressed* but were being claimed. I can certainly speak and write about relativity without plagiarizing Einstein.

I think it would be an interesting research problem, but I also think that it would be pretty far in the future before such a system could eliminate most of the false positives and false negatives.

A data driven AI system might be the way to attack it, but these are still subject to many false decisions.

But it needs to be an *intelligent* agent to make the call. A person can use transcripts and understand the meaning and the intent. A sufficiently sophisticated AI might also be able to do it, but it is still a bit beyond where were are, especially if you require a low fault rate.

---

Copyright is easier, since it *is* about words (pictures, sounds, etc).

Likewise, students copying things to cheat is generally easier since they will most likely be copying words rather than extracting the ideas/semantics from the words and there is an implicit assumption that the intent is that the ideas are their own.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR Google already provides a transcript for all YouTube videos.  Getting them to give it to you might be difficult.  Even with it, you may have to role your own since transcripts aren't student essays.**

**You could if you are willing to get transcriptions of every podcast**

Just like with written plagiarism detectors like Turnitin, the database of existing work, which is always growing, would need to be very large.

If the Podcast is on YouTube, Google does an automatic speech-to-text on anything uploaded, so you could at least compare between YouTube influencers, assuming Google is ok with you downloaded thousands on thousands of transcripts.
You can also pay Google cloud 0.6 cents per 15 minutes to do as many transcriptions as you want.

The hardest part will be getting high-quality transcripts.  The transcripts won't have punctuation, so off-the-shelf checkers, like Turnitin may not like them.

[The algorithm is pretty simple](https://www.algonquincollege.com/blackboard/how-does-turnitins-originality-check-work/), compare word list in the student's work with your existing database and see how many word list overlap.
Just like with Turnitin, it's not proof the student plagiarized, you'll still have to have a human in the loop.

**EDIT in response to comments**

Whatever you do, a human will have to listen to both podcasts and determine if the student podcast either said exactly what another podcast said (obvious plagiarism) **or** simply restated what was already said without adding new information or analysis.

No computer program (like Turnitin) can measure the contribution of work.  No contribution = plagiarism.

Comment: Hmmm. In the words of Turnitin: Turnitin cannot identify incidents of plagiarism. Nor can it prove that a student has not plagiarized.